# django 1.6 automatically remove or add http:// from URLField from form data

Tags: django-forms, django-views, django-1.6

I am going through the Tango With Django tutorials, I have come across a function in the forms chapter ( http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/forms.html ) that I cannot get to work.

Admittedly I am going through the tutorial using Python 3.3 and Django 1.6, however so far I've been able to move through the tutorials.

The `clean` function `forms.py` is supposed to clean the URLField:

```
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="input page title")
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="input page URL")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    def clean(self, cleaned_data):
        cleaned_data = super(PageForm, self).clean()
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')

        if url and not url.startswith('http://'):
            url = 'http://' + url
            cleaned_data['url'] = url

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('title', 'url', 'views')
```

Here is an excerpt from the `add_page.html` template:

```
<form id="page_form" method="POST" action="/rango/category/{{category_name_url}}/add_page/">

        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <p></p>
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}

        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="create page" />
        <br>
</form>
```

As a workaround I have adjusted the `forms.py` `url` function to work this way per the official Django docs, although it is not my preferred method:

```
url = forms.URLField(
    max_length=200, help_text="input page URL", initial='http://')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this issue too. My problem was that a pop up constantly showed when entering a url string missing `http://`, saying "Please enter a URL". So the `clean()` call never had a chance to happen.

I think this is because the default widget for a `URLfield` in a form performs a check. By doing the following, the clean() code got a chance to happen and add an eventual missing "http://"

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
...
url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, 
                     help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.", 
                     initial="http://",
                     widget=TextInput)
```

The default is `widget=UrlInput`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that input value in the url field in the form should have a prefix of "http://" when saved whether the user has inputted it or not this line is already correct:

```
url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="input page URL", initial='http://')
```

try this:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> url = forms.URLField(initial='http://')
>>> print url.clean('google.com')
http://google.com/
```

No need to implement clean() method in the form.

Update 1:

In PageForm class you have to make a clean_url() method that do what you want with the input and in save() method assign the cleaned data to an object you want tot save. Hint: Take a look at my django form [forms.py](https://github.com/ronbeltran/Python-Jobs-PH/blob/master/apps/accounts/forms.py)

Comment: what I want it to do is either add or remover the http:// depending on whether or not it was part of the user's input.

Comment: @user1026169 so what you mean is that when the user inputted in the form with 'http://example.com' in the clean() method you will remove the 'http://' or when the user inputted in the form just 'example.com' in the clean() method you will add 'http://'? whats the point? what is it that your really want to do with the value in the url field?

Comment: if someone just puts `example.com` i'd like it to become `http://example.com`, if someone puts `http://example.com` i'd like it to remain as is.  i don't want the urlfield to have http:// in it already.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another answer here that I learnt from Daniel's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39642072/1526703)

The validation message "Please enter a URL" is *not* coming from Django. Its coming from the browser which is trying to validate it on the client side (because the `type` is set to `"url"` in the input field I think). To not let the browser validate it, just put `novalidate` attribute in the form:

```
<form id="page_form" method="POST" ... novalidate>
```